# jQuery XML calls make a default for 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I'm using a jQuery ajax call to get several entries from a large set of data and write it out into a table.

I want to change the settings of the ajax calls so that if no entry exists for a given ajax call jQuery should return 0 instead of undefined, is this possible?

*Edit:*

My call to the file is as follows

```
$.get('http://ontariosheep.org/mobile/data/data_osi2.php',function(data){
            $('.content').empty();
            $(data).find('market').each(function(){
...
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is, assuming the file that is called returns no data at all (completely empty), something like this should work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test.html',
    success: function(data) {
        processData(data);
    }, 
    error: function() {
        processData(0); 
    }
});

function processData(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: I don't have the $.ajax({ section in my code, I've added the section of my code where I connect to the XML.